# create history navigation

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, html5-history

I am developping a client side application with jquery and want to save all pages visited in appli for return to them.

I use **history API** for it.

How I can show all URL visited?

Thank you

Comment: visited since  application is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try **Storage.js**

"*Provides a simple interface for storing data such as user preferences. The storage plugin is useful for saving and retreiving data from the user's browser. For newer browsers, HTML 5's localStorage is used. If localStorage isn't supported, then cookies are used instead. Retrievable data is limited to the same domain*".

https://sites.google.com/site/daveschindler/jquery-html5-storage-plugin